# NHibernate - Converting DateTime to String inside select throws exception

Tags: c#, datetime, nhibernate, queryover

I'm using NHibernate and I have a query in which im trying to select the datetime and convert it to string:

```
DateDTO dateDto = null;
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("he-IL");

var dates = _session.QueryOver<Date>()
    .Where(x => x.Client.Id == clientId)
    .Where(x => x.IsVisible != 0)
    .SelectList(lst => lst
        .Select(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => dateDto.Id)
        .Select(x => x.DateTime.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy",ci)).WithAlias(() => dateDto.Date))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<DateDTO>())
    .List<DateDTO>();
```

Which throws the following exception:

> variable 'x' of type 'Form2.Entities.Date' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't call `ToString` like that inside of the QueryOver query. You may want to use a SQL formula or format the date after the query comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: NHibernate translates QueryOver queries into SQL. It does not know how to convert the following expression into SQL:

```
Select(x => x.DateTime.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy",ci))
```

Which is why you get the error. You have a few options:

1. **Do some post-processing on the results to get the desired date format**. This is the easiest fix. You could write something like this:

   ```
   var dates = session.QueryOver<Date>()
       .Where(x => x.IsVisible != 0)
       .SelectList(lst => lst
           .Select(x => x.Id)
           .Select(x => x.DateTime))
           .List<object[]>()
       .Select(o => new DateDTO 
       {
           Id = (int)o[0],
           Date = ((DateTime)o[1]).ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy", ci) 
       });
   ```
2. **Write a custom SQL function to format the date on the database side.** This is a little more work, but the end result might look a little cleaner. This implementation will depend on your SQL dialect. This example uses the `FORMAT` function, available on SQL Server 2014:

   ```
   ISQLFunction formatFunction =
       new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.String, "FORMAT(?1, 'dddd dd MMM yyy', 'he-IL')");

   DateDTO dateDto = null;

   session.QueryOver<Date>()
       .Where(x => x.IsVisible != 0)
       .SelectList(lst => lst
           .Select(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => dateDto.Id)
           .Select(Projections.SqlFunction(
               formatFunction,
               NHibernateUtil.String,
               Projections.Property<Date>(x => x.DateTime))
           ).WithAlias(() => dateDto.Date))
       .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<DateDTO>())
       .List<DateDTO>()
       .Dump();
   ```

   This generates the following SQL:

   ```
   SELECT
       this_.Id as y0_,
       FORMAT(this_.DateTime, 'dddd dd MMM yyy', 'he-IL') as y1_ 
   FROM
       Date this_ 
   WHERE
       not (this_.IsVisible = @p0);
   ```

   You may not even need to create a custom function if the NHibernate dialect you're using already supports it.

   I have a [blog post](http://www.andrewwhitaker.com/blog/2014/08/15/queryover-series-part-7-using-sql-functions/) about using SQL functions inside of your queries, if you're interested in going that route. (Full disclosure: this is my personal blog).

Comment: Alright, so first of all this blog is awesome and truly amazing, im facing another problem which i think you can help me with. Can you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821120/nhibernate-lists-on-selectlist